# Hive performance increase

Tags: hive

I am dealing with a database (2.5 GB) having some tables only 40 row to some having 9 million rows data.
when I am doing any query for large table it takes more time.
I want results in less time

small query on table which have 90 rows only-->

```
hive> select count(*) from cidade; 
Time taken: 50.172 seconds
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value>
<description>Default block replication.
The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.block.size</name>
<value>131072</value>
<description>Default block replication.
The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

does these setting affects performance of hive?
    `dfs.replication=3`
    `dfs.block.size=131072`

can i set it from hive prompt as

```
hive>set dfs.replication=5
```

Is this value remains for a perticular session only ?

or Is it better to change it in .xml file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing is that `select count(*)` will cause hive start a map reduce job.

You may think this is very fast like mysql query.

But even a simplest map reduce job in hadoop, the total time is consist of submit to job tracker, assign task to task tracker and etc. So the total time at lease several ten secs.

try `select count(*)` on a big table. The time will not increase to much.

So, you need understand hive and hadoop deal big data.

Answer (score 2):

`dfs.replication` shouldn't impact the run-time of your hive queries. It's a property exposed from hdfs-site.xml that determines how many HDFS nodes does a block of data get replicated to. `dfs.replication` of 3 would mean each block of data is on 3 nodes (in total). Consequently, it's not for a particular session.

Comment: which are other parameters which will increase performance sir ?